# Is a 1-hour layover in Düsseldorf enough?

Tags: layovers, moroccan-citizens, dusseldorf, eurowings

I have a flight from Tangier, Morocco, to Vienna, Austria, connecting in Düsseldorf. I have Moroccan citizenship, so I want to know if passport control will be a hassle. I will arrive in Düsseldorf at 4 am if that's helpful.

It's the same airline company Eurowings.

Answer (score 3):

That depends very much on how this flight was exactly booked. I strongly recommend reading this page https://www.eurowings.com/en/faq/plan-trip/at-the-airport.html and figuring out which scenario applies to your specific details.

As a budget carrier Eurowings has only limited support for connecting flights and in many cases you have to collect bags, clear customs, check-in and go through security again. If that's the case, you have very little chance of making this connection.

The FAQ page I linked spells out the details for Berlin, Hannover, Stuttgart and Cologne, but unfortunately not for Duesseldorf.

And yes: you will have to go through immigration in Duesseldorf. How ling this will take at 4am in the morning is anyone's guess.

Comment: On a flight from Morocco with a Moroccan passport? Better be the first out of the plane.